# Smalltalk Pharo String concatenation instead of streams

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

why would the following code:

```
| list types |
list := Heap new.
types := #('a' 'b' 'c').
types do:[ :t |
    1 to:9 do:[ :i |
        list add:(t, i asString).
        ].
    ].
^ list
```

issue the `String concatenation instead of streams` warning in a method in Pharo?
Clicking the [**?**] button shows:

> **String concatenation instead of streams**
>   Check for code using string concatenation inside some iteration message.

Am I doing something that can be done easier with streams? What I want to achieve is to create a *list* of all values **a1** to **a9**, **b1** to **b9** and **c1** to **c9**.

Comment: The rule is about "schlemiel the painter algorithm" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky but it's obvisously a false positive here

Comment: I see. As Joel Spolsky "mentioned" I hadn't encountered this problem before, nor have I been taught to avoid this type of wasteful use of resources. I understand that this is a false positive, but knowing about it helps much more whenever the problem arises.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It complains because of the part `t, i asString` that is inside a collection loop (you can look at the actual implementation of the rule in the class `RBStringConcatenationRule`.

Normally string concatenation is discouraged because it's slower and more memory intense (*IIRC about the memory*).

So if you are doing some heavy concatenation (connecting a lots of parts into a single string), stream is preferable: you can look at most `printOn:` methods in the system to see it in action.

However in trivial cases concatenation with `,` is just fine, the warning rule is just too broad. Warnings are just that... warnings that something *might* be wrong, or that something *might* be written better.

Speaking of better writing, in Smalltalk it is preferable to use specialized collection methods (`select:`,`collect:`,...) over the overly-generic `do:`, e.g.

```
| list types |
types := #('a' 'b' 'c').
list := types flatCollect: [ :t | (1 to: 9) collect: [ :i | t , i asString ].
^ Heap withAll: list
```

(and if you don't need `Heap` you can just return the third line directly and not have the `list` tempvar.

Comment: Indeed, I had not thought about the specialized functions. This makes code a lot cleaner!

Answer (score 1):

To mininize the number of created objects, you could do like this:

```
| list types digits |

list := Heap new.
types := #($a $b $c).
digits := (1 to: 9) collect: #asCharacterDigit.

types do: [ :t | 
    digits do: [ :d |
        list 
            add: ((String new: 2)
                at: 1 put: t;
                at: 2 put: d;
                yourself)
          ] ].
^ list
```

So you are not creating interim strings and intervals. Nor conversions from integer to string.